# Invalidate Session of a specific user

Tags: jsf, session, authentication, invalidation

So for my webapp, if I remove a user that is currently logged in, and I want to invalidate his/her session. So that as soon as he/she refresh the page or navigate, they are no longer log in. The way I have now is that if a User logged in successfully, I will store the user object in my `SessionScoped` bean, and store the `HttpSession` to the `Application Map`. Below is my code

This is my `SessionScoped` bean

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    User user = UserDAO.findById(userId, password);
    Map<String, Object> appMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
             getExternalContext().getApplicationMap();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
             getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    appMap.put(userId, session);
}
```

Is this a correct approach? If so, how do I clean up my application map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is this a correct approach?*

There are basically 2 ways.

1. Store the `HttpSession` handle in the application scope by the user ID as key so that you can get a handle of it and invalidate it. This may work for a small web application running on a single server, but may not work on a web application running on a cluster of servers, depending on its configuration.

   I would only store it in *another* map in the application scope, not directly in the application scope like as you did, so that you can easier get an overview of all users and that you can guarantee that an arbitrary user ID  won't clash with an existing application scoped managed bean name, for example.
2. Add a new boolean/bit column to some DB table associated with the user which is checked on every HTTP request. If the admin sets it to `true`, then the session associated with the request will be invalidated and the value in the DB will be set back to `false`.

---

> *how do I clean up my application map?*

You could use [`HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29) for this. E.g.

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    User user = (User) event.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    if (user != null) {
        Map<User, HttpSession> logins = (Map<User, HttpSession>) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
        logins.remove(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding point 1. - I think there is no difference between your and Harry's approach. Both solutions involve using collections which are not shared between servers.

Comment: @BalusC: why is it that I should NOT store my `HttpSession` in `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap();`, but store in `Map<User, HttpSession>` in my `ApplicationScoped` bean, BalusC?

Comment: @hayker: I didn't mean to say that, but I now also see the ambiguity. I've removed the ambiguity from the answer and clarified it.

Comment: @BalusC: I see your updated. Regard to `HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed()`, you get the `Map<User, HttpSession>` back from the session. I thought that the `Map` is at `Application Scoped` level, not `Session Scoped`.

Comment: @Harry: the `ServletContext` represents the application scope. There's no other way to obtain it in the `HttpSessionListener` than through the `HttpSession`. The `ExternalContext#getApplicationMap()` maps as attributes of `ServletContext`.

Comment: @BalusC: I see. So I created an `ApplicationScoped` managed bean, inside the `@PostContruct` annotated `init()`, I initialize the `Map<User, HttpSession> loginMap`, then I do `((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).setAttribute("logins", loginMap);` Does that sound right, BalusC?

Comment: No, just make it a property of the application scoped managed bean. The managed bean itself is available as a servlet context attribute. But you can also let the bean class implement `HttpSessionListener` so that you don't need to fiddle like that. You just access the map property of the bean directly.

Comment: @BalusC: I ran into another issue. It look to me like `Map<String, HttpSession>` cannot be serialized. When I add `Map<String, HttpSession>` to `ApplicationScoped` managed bean that implements `Serializable`, it return error message `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade`. Any idea how to work around this, BalusC?

Comment: I saw your other question. Making it an application scoped bean is a bad idea after all. Make it a `@WebListener` which implements `ServletContextListener, HttpSessionListener`. On `contextInitialized()`, create the user-session map. On `sessionDestroyed()`, remove the session by current user.

Comment: @BalusC: I finally get it to work using application scoped bean. I just saw your comment about it :( so sad. But I will look into `@WebListener` tonight. Thank you BalusC

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use your approach (with some modifications proposed by @BalusC) plus some notification mechanism (to make it work in distributed environment). You can do one of the following:

1. Use a topic queue subscribed by all your servers. When you remove user from your admin panel the JMS message will be created and sent to the topic. Every server will be responsible for invalidating the user session if it exists on the particular server (if the session is referenced in servletContext map).
2. Implement some action to invalidate the user session and run this action on every server in the cluster (The admin panel should send HTTP request to every server).
3. Use JGroups and TCP reliable multicast.

All of these solutions are not simple but much faster than polling the DB server on every request.