# Invalidating specific user's session causing own JSF page's navigation to break

Tags: java, jsf, session, invalidation

I'm currently maintaining a Map of all currently active HTTPSessions in an `@ApplicationScoped` bean. (As per suggestions here, and in various other topics: [Invalidate Session of a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219393/invalidate-session-of-a-specific-user))

I'm using a `@WebListener` implementing `HttpSessionListener`'s `sessionCreated` method to add to the list of current sessions, and removing it on `sessionDestroyed`.

Admin users can access this list from a JSF (Richfaces 4.3.1) page and selectively invalidate specific sessions.

**The problem is**, when the logged in Admin (session A) selects and calls `session.invalidate()` to invalidate a user's session from the list (say, session B), the Admin's page (or session?) itself becomes broken, where links/actions on the *current* page are still processed (I see action methods being hit from console output), but no redirection or navigation works (appart from the logout link which calls invalidate on session A, and then redirects to the login page successfully). No errors or warnings show in the console, and this broken behaviour persists even after closing the browser window and reopening it back into the same session (A).

From looking in Chrome's Network tab I see each attempt at a redirect create a solitary POST, but nothing else.

Most of our navigation is set up in faces-config.xml like so:

```
<navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{logoutAction.doLogout}</from-action>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
</navigation-case>
```

I'm completely out of ideas, especially since all advice online seems to point to what I'm currently doing... can anybody explain why this might happen, or speculate on what I might be doing wrong or how to fix it?

Thanks, let me know if any better info is needed.

**Using:**

- Java EE 6
- JSF 2.1
- Jboss AS 7.1.1
- Richfaces 4.3.1

**Edit:**

Cut-down code samples...

Bean which holds the map of sessions (each in a custom wrapper object, `SessionUserFacade`, to hold additional user info):

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppSessionsStateBean implements Serializable {

    private final Map<String, SessionUserFacade> currentSessions = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, SessionUserFacade>());

    public void addSession(HttpSession session) {
        currentSessions.put(session.getId(), new SessionUserFacade(null, session));
    }

    public void removeSession(HttpSession session) {
        currentSessions.get(session.getId()).setSession(null);
        currentSessions.remove(session.getId());
    }

    public Map<String, SessionUserFacade> getCurrentSessions() {
        return currentSessions;
    }
}
```

Simple @WebListener to call app-scoped bean:

```
@WebListener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{

    @Inject
    private AppSessionsStateBean appStateBean;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        appStateBean.addSession(httpSessionEvent.getSession());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        appStateBean.removeSession(httpSessionEvent.getSession());
    }
}
```

Action method accessed from the front-end, in a `@Named` `@ViewAccessScoped` bean (invalidateSession is just a direct wrapper for `HttpSession.invalidate();`):

```
public void invalidateSelected() {

    for (SessionUserFacade session : selectionItems) {

        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            session.invalidateSession();
        }
    }
    clearSelection();
}
```

Called from:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="btnConfirmLogout" action="#{sessionManagementAction.invalidateSelected}"
        value="Logout Selected" oncomplete="#{rich:component('forceLogoutPopup')}.hide()"/>
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you store user's session reference in a map and where you invalidate a user's session ?

Comment: @Apurv I've added some relevant bits of code to the question (tried not to cut out anything vital). Does that help at all?

Comment: To the `invalidateSelected` method where are you passing which session id needs to be invalidated ?

Comment: @Apurv The `for (SessionUserFacade session : selectionItems) {` line loops through a list of selected session objects to invalidate, which gets populated via AJAX from a RichFaces table in the front end.

Comment: Can you share the code where selected session id's are passed from UI to action handler and the `selectionItems` list is prepared ?

Comment: @Apurv Selection List is created essentially just the same as example code from this part of the [Richfaces Showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=exTableSelection&skin=blueSky) , using selectionListener and extendedDataTable selection attribute.

Comment: If you comment out `session.invalidateSession();` in `invalidateSelected` method you still get the same problem?

Comment: @dcernahoschi Nope, without the `session.invalidateSession();` everything acts as expected, and the page doesn't break. It's defintely directly related to something that happens when invalidating a session, somehow.

Comment: Could you post the code for your SessionUserFacade, or specifically the invalidateSession method that you are calling?