# JSF logout other users while maintaining my active session.

Tags: jsf, session, jsf-2, ejb, invalidation

I am trying to logout a user in a jsf application as an admin while I maintain my session but the efforts are not yielding anything. 
A user can invalidate their own session easily in my application but what I want to achieve is a situation where another user say an admin can log out other users.

So my main question is how can I access the sessions of other users and is it possible to store the jsf sessions in the database?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalidate-session-of-a-specific-user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219393/invalidate-session-of-a-specific-user)

Comment: What comes to my mind as an easy solution is to have an `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean with a map and all the current logged users stored there. Bring access to it only with administrator credentials. When you want to invalidate a session, mark as invalid in the map. You should make all the user requests check that map in each request and, if session invalid, make the invalidation process for the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code creates a Sessionlistener that manages the open sessions in a list that can be injected. Then you can inject the list of sessions via `@SessionList`

SessionListener.java

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  @Inject
  @SessionList
  private List<HttpSession> sessions;

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    session.add(event.getSession());
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        session.remove(event.getSession());
  } 

}
```

SessionList.java

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface SessionList {
}
```

SessionProducer.Java

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SessionProducer {
   private List<HttpSession> session;

   @Produces
   @SessionList
   public void List<Session> getSessions() {
      if(sessions == null) sessions = new LinkedList<HttpSession>();
      return sessions;
   }
}
```